# aklog: a pioctl failed while obtaining tokens for cell xxx - what to do?

Tags: networking

OS was changed from ubuntu 11.04 to ubuntu 12.04.LTS. Now I cannot reach my remote directories:
kinit -5 user@XXXX
aklog XXXX

These worked before. What to do now?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that `openafs` daemon is started?

Try `sudo /etc/init.d/openafs start`